# Sound distortion in PulseAudio on Gentoo

Tags: linux, audio, gentoo, pulse-audio

I'm running Gentoo Linux on an amd64-powered PC. My soundcard is `Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)`. I'm also using PulseAudio. The problem is that sound frequently goes laggy and distorted, especially in Flash, especially in high-resolution videos and heavy flash applications. It also does so in desktop applications. The distortion is quite strange: at a random moment, a piece of sound that was played about half a second ago, is played again, and this is repeated up to three times during a single lag. Steam games have a special type of lag: sound can randomly start coming out with a delay of approx. 1 second, permanently. This problems take place until I restart PulseAudio, but they return in a short time.

`lspci -v:`

```
Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device a102
Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16     
Memory at fe024000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Windows 7 x64 on this PC outputs sound without a problem. How can I fix this issue in Gentoo? The problem also existed in Debian, Ubuntu, Arch Linux run on this PC. My guess is that my soundcard just doesn't have proper support in Linux Kernel. It is integrated in the motherboard, by the way.